# SSLHandshakeFailed on mongodb server while trying to connect through java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I've been trying to connect a mongodb server with TLS 1.2 via java driver however getting handshake failure which I cannot understand why. Here is my setup

- MongoDB Server 4.2.1
- mongod.conf:

```
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017

   tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    CAFile: <location-to-ca.crt>
    certificateKeyFile: <location-to-server.pem>
    disabledProtocols: TLS1_0,TLS1_1
```

- JDK: 1.8.0_202
- mongo-java-driver: 3.12.3

```
private static void Tls1_2Test() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = createSSLContext();
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyToSslSettings(builder -> {
                builder.enabled(true);
                builder.context(sslContext);
                builder.invalidHostNameAllowed(true);
            })
            .build();
    try (MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(settings)) {
        for (String s : client.listDatabaseNames()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static SSLContext createSSLContext() throws Exception {

    // root CA
    TrustManagerFactory tmf;
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("<location-to-ca.crt>")) {
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
        tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null); // You don't need the KeyStore instance to come from a file.
        ks.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);
        tmf.init(ks);
    }

    // client key
    KeyManagerFactory keyFac;
    try (InputStream is = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("<location-to-client.pem>")) {
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(is, null);
        keyFac = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyFac.init(keystore, null);
    }

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(keyFac.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return sslContext;
}
```

- [KeyGen](https://gist.github.com/kevinadi/96090f6f9973ff8c2d019bbe0d9a0f70)

If I do not use CAFile or use `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true` in config, I can connect since server do not take care of trusted authority for handshake. However, I cannot find what is wrong with java code so that server does not get CA certificate to use in handshake.

Note that net.tls.CAFile in mongod config and root CA on java code pointing to the same file. I also tried to use .pem file in net.tls.CAFile but got the same result.

Here is java console when I try to connect:

```
14:39:55.501 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
14:39:55.524 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
14:39:55.536 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
14:39:55.641 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:1}
14:39:55.643 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:569)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:448)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:299)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:109)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:580)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:445)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
14:39:55.644 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Connection reset}}]
14:39:56.174 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:2}
14:39:56.174 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Connection reset}}]
14:39:56.699 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:3}
14:39:56.700 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Connection reset}}]
14:39:57.228 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:4}
14:39:57.228 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5e98521b6091fb316cd91fbe', description='null'}-127.0.0.1:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketException: Connection reset}}]

Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)
```

Here is server's log when I try to connect:

```
2020-04-16T14:39:57.227+0200 I  NETWORK  [conn4] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: no SSL certificate provided by peer: No error.; connection rejected. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:52955 (connection id: 4)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found not to use Keystore merely (because I didn't set up any Keystore to use) I used bouncy castle to read client file. Used bouncycastle 1.65 version. Here is how I achieved it:

I updated client file reading to the following

```
// client key
KeyManagerFactory keyFac;
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("<location-to-client.pem>")) {
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(null); // needs to be initialised, otherwise throws exception
    PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(fr);
    PrivateKeyInfo privateKeyInfo = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
    JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
    PrivateKey privateKey = converter.getPrivateKey(privateKeyInfo);
    JcaX509CertificateConverter certConverter = new JcaX509CertificateConverter();
    X509CertificateHolder certificateHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) pemParser.readObject();
    X509Certificate certificate = certConverter.getCertificate(certificateHolder);
    keystore.setKeyEntry("alias", privateKey, "".toCharArray(), new Certificate[]{certificate});
    keyFac = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyFac.init(keystore, "".toCharArray());
}
```